# Kubernetes cron job needs to get tag from prod rather than latest?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cron job that runs off the latest image of my repo. In the yaml definition of the cron job the image definition is like this:

```
image: 123456789.abc.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/company/myservice:latest
```

The issue is our latest tag gets updated anytime there is a merge to master in GitHub. However, the code is not deployed to prod at this point. There is no continuous deployment though so our code is not deployed in prod, however the latest code from master will be used by the cron job.

Does it work as a solution to tag a 'prod' image that the cron job will run from? In this case when we deploy, the prod image would get updated to that image. Also, if there is a rollback we would update the prod image to be the image that prod is now reverting to.

Or is there a better solution/pattern to this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create git release tags or use commit ids. Put this value in config map, and the cron job container should pull code by using this commit-id or release tag. So staging and production configs can have a different tags.

I would not recommend using `latest` tag for deployments on kubernetes. It works well with docker but not with kubernetes + docker. Create immutable image tags.
Kuberentes compares only tag, not tag + SHA.
https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/use-latest-image-tag-to-update-a-deployment/2929

Or you can use `imagePullPolicy: always` with latest tag.

Comment: I get the part about referencing a specific commit-id, but how do I obtain that id on a prod deployment?

Comment: @WilliamRoss Can you explain a bit more about prod deployment, and why would it be hard to fetch this commit id  ?

Comment: I'm able to get the id of the pod easily but not sure on the commit id, do I need to exec into the pod and find it this way by looking at the git repo inside the pod, or is there an easier way through kubectl?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Can you explain how are you creating deployments and how does your deployment process work ?

Comment: To perform a deployment we use a prod context and use a Makefile which performs the rollout. Underlying the Makefile are kubectl commands. The cronjob is completely separate, but uses the lastest image and should instead read from whatever image is currently deployed in prod (handling scenarios such as rollbacks as well).

Comment: @WilliamRoss How does latest image get updated if you don't have a CD system in place ?

Comment: Anytime something is merged to the master branch in GitHub the latest tag is updated.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you should set up two Git repos of your application, for example master and prod. You may then use Jenkins to build and deploy those repose to Kubernetes on commit (prod branch can be set to build on demand). So master branch will push to latest tag, and prod branch will push to prod branch. Then you specify tag latest in your job manifest. That's how it is configured in most cases.

Any questions?

Comment: Do you mean two separate branches, or different repos? Using a kubernetes 'Makefile' for deployments rather than Jenkins.

Comment: Is your makefile in the same branch with the committed code?  If so, then you can trivially get the commit for your current checkout, either through an ENV var for whatever process is kicking off the makefile, or just have the makefile do a `git rev-parse --verify --short HEAD` and use that within your makfile for tagging the docker image AND supplying the value to kubernettes